# Symfony 2 how to send invitation

Tags: symfony, invitation

I  created  a website using symfony2 I installed and  setup fosuserbundle   and it works  perfectly.
I have  users  with  the previlege manager and  I would like  them to be able to send  email invitations  to  other  users  in order  to register  to my site  but  to a very    specific usergroup  same  as  the invitation sender .

what  is the best approach to do this ? 
 thanks  in advance .

Answer (score 1):

the only way i can think of is that you'd have to keep track of the invatations, so an entity of who the inviter is, who the recipient is (email address and name if provided), and a random unique token of about 25 characters so that you can look up do a reverse lookup on who the inviter is when they accept the invite.  This way you can automatically assign them a user group based on who the inviter is.